Decode text returned from OSX Mail Raw Source email in Applescript
I have an applescriptscript to extract a section of text from the the raw source of an email in OSX Mail. That works fine.
However, the text in the raw source email is encoded and is returned by the applescript in the same format
Is there a way I can get the applescript to convert/decode the returned text?
These are two examples of the text in the raw source email, which is returned in the same format by the applescript:
That&#39;s great thank you, I&#39;ve just replied
It hasn=E2=80=99t been available

Does this answer your question? Is there a way to decode a Quoted-Printable encoding using ApplescriptObjc? See also https://www.macscripter.net/t/native-applescript-html-entity-decoder/70609

This solution turned out to be the perfect https://www.macscripter.net/t/decode-text-returned-from-osx-mail-raw-source-email/75742/3

This was the solution which worked for me - by Nigel_Garvey on macscripter Decode text from Raw Source Email
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) or later
use framework "Foundation"
-- use scripting additions
set |⌘| to current application
set input to |⌘|'s class "NSString"'s stringWithString:(input)
-- Replace any line breaks in the text with HTML versions.
set input to input's stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:("\\R") withString:("<br/>") ¬
    options:(|⌘|'s NSRegularExpressionSearch) range:({0, input's |length|()})
-- Convert the "HTML" string to data and thence to an attributed string.
set HTMLData to input's dataUsingEncoding:(|⌘|'s NSUTF8StringEncoding)
set attributedString to |⌘|'s class "NSAttributedString"'s alloc()'s initWithHTML:(HTMLData) ¬
    documentAttributes:(missing value)
-- Extract a string with the HTML entities interpreted.
set output to attributedString's |string|()
-- Percent encode any existing percent signs in the string.
set output to output's stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:("%") withString:("%25")
-- Convert any apparent "equals" encoding to percent encoding.
set output to output's stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:("=([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})") withString:("%$1") ¬
    options:(|⌘|'s NSRegularExpressionSearch) range:({0, output's |length|()})
-- Interpret the percent encoding and return.
return (output's stringByRemovingPercentEncoding()) as text

